# Using scale_color with a variable of class date produces Error: as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, colors, tidyverse

I'm trying to color by date with ggplot2, but when I try to customize the color using `scale_color_gradient2`, I get an error saying `Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied`.

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the origin to `scale_color_gradient2`.

I've provided an example below. Any advice?

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
day <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 100)

myData <- data.frame(x1, x2, day)

# this plot works as expected
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x1, y = x2, color = day)) + geom_point()

# scale_color_gradient2() asks for an origin, but I can't figure out how to supply one
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x1, y = x2, color = day)) + geom_point() +
    scale_color_gradient2()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things need to be added to `scale_color_gradient2`: `trans = "date"`* and a sensible `midpoint` (default is 0). I used `mean` 'day'. Note that you need the numeric version of the mean in `scale`:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x1, y = x2, color = day)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient2(trans = "date", midpoint = as.numeric(mean(myData$day)))
```

[image]

---

You may want to change the default breaks and labels in the legend. First, create a sequence of breaks, using `seq` or `pretty`:

```
brk <- seq.Date(min(myData$day), max(myData$day), by = "3 month")
# brk <- pretty(myData$day)
```

Set `breaks` and `labels` with desired `format` in your scale:

```
scale_color_gradient2(trans = "date", midpoint = as.numeric(mean(myData$day)), 
                      breaks = brk,
                      labels = format(brk, "%Y-%m"))
```

---

Edit following comment:

### Use `scale_color_gradient2` with `POSIXct` variable

Add `trans = "time"` and a sensible `midpoint` to `scale_color_gradient2`. Here I use a mean 'time'. Note that you need the numeric version of the mean in `scale`.

```
# some data
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1, time = as.POSIXct("2019-02-15 12:00") + 1:10)

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = time)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient2(trans = "time", midpoint = as.numeric(mean(d$time)))
```

[image]

---

Possibly change breaks and labels in the legend, e.g.

```
brk <- pretty(d$time)

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = time)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient2(trans = "time", midpoint = as.numeric(mean(d$time)),
                        breaks = brk, labels = format(brk, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

---

*In the current version of `ggplot2` (3.1.0), it is not obvious from the docs that `trans = "date"` and `trans = "time"` exist. They are mentioned neither in the `trans` argument in `?scale_color_gradient` et al., nor in `?continuous_scale`. However, I submitted an issue so the docs will hopefully be updated in the next release.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. 

As a follow-up, is there a way to use POSIXct class in `scale_color_gradient` without converting it to a Date class?